# Remover campos TimePicker

Tags: php, javascript, timepicker

Estou tentando remover os campos de segundo, milisegundo e timezone mas não consigo. Verifiquei a documentação, coloquei *showTimezone: false* mas ainda assim aparece. Como posso proceder?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo que estou usando:

```js
<script>
$(function() {
$('#hora_parada').timepicker({
 timeOnlyTitle: 'Selecione a Hora',
 timeText: 'Hora Selecionada',
 hourText: 'Hora',
 minuteText: 'Minuto',
 currentText: 'Agora',
 closeText: 'Selecionar',
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recentemente apliquei essa configuração no ambiente que trabalho.
Veja abaixo:

```
 $(element).timepicker({
                            minuteStep: 1,
                            showSeconds: true,
                            showMeridian: false,
                            defaultTime: true
 });
```

para não apresentar os segundos, basta colocar o `showSeconds: false`

Comment: Coloquei assim mas não adianta, aparecem todas opções ainda.

Comment: Tente usar isso: $('#timeformatExample1').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i'});